# Do I need to include the full name of a fellowship in CV?

Tags: cv

I received a fellowship from my university, its full name is very long:

> "[Name 1] Endowed Fellowship Fund, in Memory of Professor [Name 2]."

On my university's website, I've seen multiple ways to call this fellowship:

> [Name 1] fellowship awards;
> [Name 1] endowed fellowship awards;
> [Name 1] fellowship

So my question is how to include this fellowship on my CV? Do I need to provide the full name in the description? If I use the abberviated name, should I use the singular form ("award" instead of "awards", "fellowship" instead of "fellowships")?

Comment: Are you a grad student?

Comment: @Azor Ahai -him- I am an undergraduate senior :)

Comment: Is the memorial fellowship any different than not?

Comment: @Azor Ahai -him- No, this fellowship is more like an academic award

Comment: No, is there any difference between receiving this award with the designation "in Memory of ..." and not receiving that designation.

Comment: @Azor Ahai -him- Oh, there's no difference

Comment: Why do you think it is a problem if the name is long?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily, CVs can usually be as long as you want, so the name length doesn't matter too much.

It would be weird to put "Endowed Fellowship Fund" on your application, because you didn't receive a "Fund," you received a "Fellowship."

I would also ensure you put "Fellowship," not "Award" as the former is less ambiguous and more prestigious. An award could just be an acknowledgement.

With internal awards, it's important to use the full name so that people in other institutions can find it, if they wish. Also, if Professor Name2 has a good reputation, that can only help you.

So in summary, I would write:

> Professor [Name2] Endowed Fellowship, in Memory of Professor [Name2]

If you really want to, you could (1) drop the "Endowed," since it is named without it elsewhere, and (2) use only last names instead of full names.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! The fellowship includes a monetary award, in this case, should I include 'Endowed' and 'Fund'?

Comment: @IGY No, I explained why you don't need "Fund." If it makes you worry less, just include "Endowed."

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for shortening the fellowship name in an "official" place like your CV. Even if you are dealing with a page limit on your CV, this is not going to make any meaningful difference.

Not using the full name can lead to potential for confusion, as it will not be clear to the reader whether the shortened name refers to a different scheme or not.

Finally, it seems that [Name1] gave a lot of money to keep the memory of [Name2] alive, and it would feel somewhat disrespectful to me to sabotage this by leaving out [Name2].

Comment: Thank you, that helps!